# General understanding of ros-canopen

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, joints

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
over the last couple days i tried to understand the concept of ros-canopen.
I do have a drive motor from dunkermotor which conforms to CiA 402. Also i do have a PEAK-USB adapter to connect the motor to my PC.

1. From my understanding ros_canopen provides a driver for PEAK-USB in the package [socketcan_interface](http://wiki.ros.org/socketcan_interface?distro=lunar). After some [preperation](http://wiki.ros.org/socketcan_interface?distro=lunar#Preparation) i should be able to test my setup with can-utils.
2. For usage with other ROS nodes i have to use either [canopen_chain_node](http://wiki.ros.org/canopen_chain_node?distro=kinetic) or [canopen_motor_node](http://wiki.ros.org/canopen_motor_node?distro=lunar) whereby canopen_motor_node implements the CiA 402 profiles. For configuration i have to follow the description on [canopen_chain_node/Configuration](http://wiki.ros.org/canopen_chain_node?distro=lunar#Configuration). I guess i only have to set a single node here since i only want to drive a single motor for testing purposes. The .eds/.dcf files should be provided by the manufacturer of my motor right? If not, can i write it by myself?
3. With canopen_motor_node i really get lost. What i don't get is what it all has to do with [ros_control](http://wiki.ros.org/ros_control?distro=lunar) as stated in [canopen_motor_node/Concepts](http://wiki.ros.org/canopen_motor_node?distro=lunar#Concepts). I am also confused about joints and URDF, do I really need a robot_description for driving a single motor?

So for the .launch file i would do something like this:

```
    <launch>
      <node pkg="canopen_motor_node" name="canopen_motor_node" type="canopen_motor_node" >
        <rosparam file="$(find pkgname)/params/canopen.yaml" command="load" />
      </node>
    </launch>
```

And for the .yaml i would do something like this:

```
    #driver params
    bus:
      device: can0 # socketcan network
    sync:
      interval_ms: 10 # set to 0 to disable sync
      overflow: 0 # overflow sync counter at value or do not set it (0, default)

    #canopen_chain_node params
    nodes:
      - name: node1
        id: 1
        eds_file: "$(find pkgname)/params/my_config.eds" # path to EDS/DCF file

    #canopen_motor_node params
    ...
```

edit:

For the `#canopen_motor_node params` i used configs recomended by jdeleon in the comments and close to the defaults described on [canopen_motor_node/Configuration](http://wiki.ros.org/canopen_motor_node?distro=lunar#Configuration).

```
    defaults: # optional, all defaults can be overwritten per node
      motor_allocator: canopen::Motor402::Allocator # select allocator for motor layer
      motor_layer: #settings passed to motor layer (plugin-specific)
        switching_state: 2 # (Operation_Enable), state for mode switching
      pos_to_device: "rint(rad2deg(pos)*1000)" # rad -> mdeg
      pos_from_device: "deg2rad(obj6064)/1000" # actual position [mdeg] -> rad
      vel_to_device: "rint(rad2deg(vel)*1000)" # rad/s -> mdeg/s
      vel_from_device: "deg2rad(obj606C)/1000" # actual velocity [mdeg/s] -> rad/s
      eff_to_device: "rint(eff)" # just round to integer
      eff_from_device: "0" # unset
      publish: ["6042"]
```

When i launch this i get the errors:

```
    [ERROR] [1528373326.152068579]: Could not find parameter robot_description on parameter server
    [ERROR] [1528373326.221375434]: joint node1 was not found in URDF
```

Although i am not quiet sure why i would need this i wrote an URDF file and puplished it through robot_state_publisher.
I added those lines to the beginning of my launch file.

```
    <param name="robot_description" textfile="$(find pkgname)/urdf/urdf.xml"/>
    <node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" name="rob_st_pub" >
    </node>
```

And for the URDF i wrote the urdf.xml

```
     <robot name="test_robot">
       <link name="link1" />
       <link name="link2" />

       <joint name="node1" type="continuous">
         <parent link="link1"/>
         <child link="link2"/>
       </joint>
     </robot>
```

Now i can launch my launch file without errors.

In a terminal i executed `candump can0`.

And in another terminal i executed `rosservice call /driver/init`.

I can now see a lot of traffic on my candump terminal.

I am now stuck with further communication with my motor. How do those ros_controller work, do i really need them? I would simply want my motor_node to subscribe to a topic where i can tell it target motor speeds. Is this possible?

I am really looking forward for some help, let me know if you need more information or if I am completely wrong. It's just hard to ask a specific question when you don't really understand the whole concept.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/292593/general-understanding-of-ros-canopen/) by [JulianS](https://answers.ros.org/users/35538/julians/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-05-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi JulianS,
I'm also trying to understand ros-canopen in canopen_motor_node params I have the next:

```
defaults: # optional, all defaults can be overwritten per node
  # canopen_chain_node settings ..
  motor_allocator: canopen::Motor402::Allocator # select allocator for motor layer
  #motor_layer: # settings passed to motor layer (plugin-specific)
  switching_state: 5 # (Operation_Enable), state for mode switching
  pos_to_device: "rint(rad2deg(pos)*1000)" # rad -> mdeg
  pos_from_device: "deg2rad(obj6064)/1000" # actual position [mdeg] -> rad
  vel_to_device: "rint(rad2deg(vel)*1000)" # rad/s -> mdeg/s
  vel_from_device: "deg2rad(obj606C)/1000" # actual velocity [mdeg/s] -> rad/s
  eff_to_device: "rint(eff)" # just round to integer
  #eff_from_device: "0" # unset
```

With that, I can connect correctly to the motors,
Jorge

---

Originally posted by [jdeleon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27207/jdeleon/) with karma: 133 on 2018-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-06-04**:
Please don't use an *answer* to ask a *question*. This isn't a forum. Please create a new question and reference this question instead.

**Comment by [JulianS](https://answers.ros.org/users/35538/julians/) on 2018-06-04**:
I will test this on wednesday. Do you know what the `switching_state` parameter does?
And what is happening next? Does the canopen_motor_node puplishes topics then based on the objects described in the .eds file?

**Comment by [jdeleon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27207/jdeleon/) on 2018-06-05**:
The switching state is the operation mode for the motor:
From the [wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/canopen_402)

Profiled Position 1

Velocity 2

Profiled Velocity 3

﻿Profiled Torque 4

Interpolated Position 7

Cyclic Synchronous Position 8

Cyclic Synchronous Velocity 9

Cyclic Synchronous Torque 10

**Comment by [jdeleon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27207/jdeleon/) on 2018-06-05**:
About the canopen_motor_node, I can't answer at this moment, because I'm stuck with the controller_manager

**Comment by [jdeleon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27207/jdeleon/) on 2018-06-07**:
Hi @JulianS,
did you test something? was it successful?

**Comment by [JulianS](https://answers.ros.org/users/35538/julians/) on 2018-06-07**:
Hi, yes i tested your canopen_motor_node params yesterday and i was able to comunicate with my motor. I will edit my original post with my new knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know if you have already managed to control your motors but I will answer anyway. So...

> The .eds/.dcf files should be provided by the manufacturer of my motor right? If not, can i write it by myself?

Normally this file is provided for the manufacturer to tell you which canopen objects are supported internally by the motors. Maybe you could write yourself one by using `candump` or `cansend` and listening all of the objects described by CiA in the standars and trying to find out which ones are supported by I wouldn't do that because is not worth it. Better to contact the manufacturer.

> do I really need a robot_description for driving a single motor?

Yes you need one. It is used by ros_control to control the actuators. Even if you want to control a single motor it has like a hardware configuration so it is the way to tell ROS which is your hardware configuration in order to control it.

> How do those ros_controller work, do i really need them? I would simply want my motor_node to subscribe to a topic where i can tell it target motor speeds. Is this possible?

canopen_motor_node implements an interface between ros_control and the ros_canopen pckages. It means it adapts the software of the driver (all the canopen protocols implementations) to your physical configuration (passed by the URDF) and allows you to control it. As you may see by doing `rostopic list` once you have launched the driver, you can find the corresponding topics to the controller you implemented. you could see topics like /your-controller-name/cmd_vel that allows you to send velocity commands to move your motor. I'm not sure if this topic appears for all the controllers but at least it is the case for DiffDriveController.

---

Originally posted by [af.villamil231](https://answers.ros.org/users/40998/af.villamil231/) with karma: 13 on 2019-07-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1